# How to remove properties of objects in ArrayList

Tags: java, spring, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

I have an end point which returns large chunk of data and I want to remove some part of it.

For example:

**Class A**

```
public class A{

private String id;
private Date createOn;
private String processed;
}
```

**Class B**

```
public class B extends MongoDBObject{
private String id;
private Date createOn;
private String processed;
}
```

**Controller**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v1/read")
public class ReadController{

@Autowired
private StatementBundleService bundleService;

@CrossOrigin
@GetMapping(value = "/statementBundles")
public List<A> listStatements() {
   List<A> result = new ArrayList<A>();

   List<B> bundles = bundleService.getAll();

   for(B bundle: bundles) {
       result.add(new A(bundle));
   }

   return result;
}
```

I am trying to figure out what is the best way return the list of `A` without the properties "processed" from both class `A` and class `B`.

Should I only use `for each` loop or `iterator`? Also should I set properties to `null` or some other approach?

Comment: How is `A` created from a `B`?

Comment: why does `new A(bundle)` work? Could you just modify that constructor to not copy `processed` ?

Comment: There is constructor in A with argument B that sets the properties. The problem is that Class A is used on other places so i cant modify this constructor

Comment: Is it possible to extract an interface from A and use it instead? Then you could create several implementations of A depeneding on certain requirements. One of them would not copy the value of `processed` from the initializing `B`-object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt if it is possible to alter the property without iterating it.
Though you can try java8 for fast and simple output. Have a look in the soln.

```
public class Java8 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Student> myList = new ArrayList<Student>();
    myList.add(new Student(1, "John", "John is a good Student"));
    myList.add(new Student(1, "Paul", "Paul is a good Player"));
    myList.add(new Student(1, "Tom", "Paul is a good Teacher"));

    System.out.println(myList);//old list
    myList = myList.stream().peek(obj -> obj.setBiography(null)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(myList);//new list
}

/*Output*/
//[Student [id=1, Name=John, biography=John is a good Student], Student [id=1, Name=Paul, biography=Paul is a good Player], Student [id=1, Name=Tom, biography=Paul is a good Teacher]]
//[Student [id=1, Name=John, biography=null], Student [id=1, Name=Paul, biography=null], Student [id=1, Name=Tom, biography=null]]
```

}

where Student class as is

```
public class Student{
private int id;
private String Name;
private String biography;

public Student(int id, String name, String biography) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    Name = name;
    this.biography = biography;
}
public int getId() {
    return id;
}       
public String getBiography() {
    return biography;
}
public void setBiography(String biography) {
    this.biography = biography;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Student [id=" + id + ", Name=" + Name + ", biography=" + biography + "]";
}       
}
```